# SerialPort.Close() removes the serial port from components.Components

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

In C#, I have a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` component on my Windows form. I have several places in my code in which I loop like so:

```
foreach (SerialPort in components.Components)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

But each SerialPort is removed from the `components.Components` class when I run a `mySerialPort.Close()`, so it is missed by all subsequent loops. Is this a bug? Or is this intentional? Why would it behave like that by design?

The internal documentation says that the `Close()` method only disposes of the `Stream` object within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Like all other .NET framework classes, the SerialPort.Close() method calls its Dispose() method.  Inherited from its base class, Component.  Which uses the disposing pattern, calling the virtual Dispose(bool) method.  Which SerialPort overrides to close its stream.  And calls the base.Dispose(bool) method which Component uses to remove the component from the collection.

This is otherwise natural behavior, a SerialPort can be dropped on a form so it gets disposed automatically when the form closes.  And it is also entirely normal to open a port when the window is created and keep it open until it closes.  Closing the port halfway through program execution just causes trouble.  But is otherwise supported, you'll just need to keep track of the object yourself.